# Finding an equilibrium solution to a first order system of equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Given a model:

$
y''+\alpha y'+\beta y + \gamma y = -g
$

I can see that it can be converted to a system of first order equations as follows:

$y_{1}=y$, $y_{2}=y'$ and as such $y_{1}'=y'$ and $y_{2}'=y''$.

Using this I see that:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
y_{1}' \\ y_{2}'
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ -(\beta + \gamma) & -\alpha
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
y_{1} \\ y_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ -g
\end{bmatrix}
$

However, I am unsure how to use this to find an equilibrium matrix for this first order system of equations.

If it helps we are asked to show that the solution is:

$\mathbf{y_{eq}}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{-g}{\beta + \gamma} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Set $ \ y_1' \ = \ 0 \ , \ y_2' \ = \ 0 \ $ . (That's the equilibrium condition -- no changes in the variables.)  Your matrix equation is then equivalent to the system  $ \ y_2 \ + \ 0 \  = \ 0 \ \ , \ \ -(\beta + \gamma) \ y_1 \ - \ \alpha \ y_2 \ - \ g \ = \ 0 \ $ .

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming that the "equilibrium matrix" is the $2 \times 1$ matrix representing the *equilibrium point* in the $y_1$-$y_2$ plane, we can proceed as follows: since at equilibrium we have

$y_1' = y_2' = 0, \tag{1}$

the equation representing

$y'' + \alpha y' + (\beta + \gamma)y = -g \tag{2}$

becomes

$\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -(\beta + \gamma) & -\alpha \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -g \end{bmatrix}; \tag{3}$

writing this out in component form yields

$y_2 = 0, \tag{4}$

$-(\beta + \gamma)y_1 - \alpha y_2 - g = 0; \tag{5}$

substituting $y_2$ from (4) into (5) reveals that

$-(\beta + \gamma) y_1 - g = 0, \tag{6}$

or

$y_1 = -\dfrac{g}{\beta + \gamma}; \tag{7}$

thus the equilibrium point may be written as the $2 \times 1$ matrix

$\mathbf y_{\mathbf {eq}} = \begin{bmatrix} -\dfrac{g}{\beta + \gamma)} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}. \tag{8}$